# sql query to insert into columns with value from rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table as the result of a query say calc_success_rate

```
server,      service,     timestamp,     success_rate
123.23.23.2  ftp          1:00 am        1
123.23.23.2  http         1:00 am        0.5
```

I want to insert these values into another table say metrics whose structure is as follows

```
server       ftpSuccessRate     httpsuccessrate       timestamp  
123.23.23.2  1                  0.5                   1:00
```

I will be doing a join between `calc_success_rate.server` and `metrics.server` and `calc_success_rate.timestamp` and `metrics.timestamp` and insert the `ftpsuccessrate` and `httpsuccessrate`

Is it possible to do this in one query

I need an update statement something like this

```
update secondTable st 
set ftpSuccessRate = , httpSuccessRate = 
from firstTable ft 
where ft.server = st.server and ft.timestamp = st.timestamp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO SecondTable
    (server, ftpSuccessRate, httpSuccessRate, timestamp)
    SELECT server, 
           MAX(CASE WHEN service = 'ftp' THEN success_rate ELSE NULL END),
           MAX(CASE WHEN service = 'http' THEN success_rate ELSE NULL END), 
           timestamp
         FROM FirstTable
         GROUP BY server, timestamp;
```

**EDIT**: Based on the comment, here's the UPDATE version:

```
UPDATE st 
    SET ftpSuccessRate = q.ftpSuccessRate,
        httpSuccessRate = q.httpSuccessRate
    FROM (SELECT server,  
                 MAX(CASE WHEN service = 'ftp' THEN success_rate ELSE NULL END) as ftpSuccessRate, 
                 MAX(CASE WHEN service = 'http' THEN success_rate ELSE NULL END) as httpSuccessRate,  
                 timestamp 
              FROM FirstTable 
              GROUP BY server, timestamp) q 
        INNER JOIN @SecondTable st 
            ON q.server = st.server 
                AND q.timestamp = st.timestamp
```

Comment: its more of an update statement on secondTable with join between them using server and the timestamp. update secondTable st set ftpSuccessRate = , httpSuccessRate = from firstTable ft where ft.server = st.server and ft.timestamp = st.timestamp

Comment: @user373201: I'll modify my answer but the subject of your question clearly states "sql query to *insert*"

Comment: @user373201 - The UPDATE assumes that the existence of a "ftp" record in the first table guarantees an "http" record as well.  Is that correct?  If so, this works great :)

Comment: @JoeStefanelli - Still requires an ISNULL or COALESCE so as to avoid replacing existing values with NULL?  (Assumes FirstTable never has NULL as a legitimate value though)

Comment: @Dems: Possibly. Those are business rules beyond what was given within the scope of this question.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli - Without such a business rule, I'd keep the original UPDATE you posted.  Both versions have the same behaviour in this case?

Comment: @Dems My first attempt at the update was syntactically incorrect. The GROUP BY has to be encapsulated in the sub query.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO
  youTable
SELECT
  server,
  MAX(CASE WHEN service = 'ftp'  THEN success_rate END)   AS  ftpSuccessRate,
  MAX(CASE WHEN service = 'http' THEN success_rate END)   AS httpSuccessRate,
  timestamp
FROM
  yourOtherTable
GROUP BY
  server,
  timestamp
```

Or as an update of existing records...

```
UPDATE
  yourOtherTable
SET
  ftpSuccessRate  = COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN service = 'ftp'  THEN success_rate END), yourOtherTable.ftpSuccessRate ),
  httpSuccessRate = COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN service = 'http' THEN success_rate END), yourOtherTable.httpSuccessRate)
FROM
  yourOtherTable
LEFT JOIN
  yourtable
    ON  yourTable.server    = yourOtherTable.server
    AND yourTable.timestamp = yourOtherTable.timestamp
GROUP BY
  yourOtherTable.server
  yourOtherTable.timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE 
  metrics SET 
      ftpSuccessRate = (CASE WHEN service = 'ftp' THEN success_rate ELSE NULL END),
      httpsuccessrate = (CASE WHEN service = 'http' THEN success_rate ELSE NULL END)    
  FROM 
    calc_success_rate 
  WHERE 
    metrics.server = calc_success_rate.Server
```